# How to make a carousel using Google.Cloud.Dialogflow.V2 Carousel for dialogflow?

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

Im trying to build a webhook for dialogflow with help from nuget package Google.Cloud.Dialogflow.V2.
Im running the code with .Net Core 2.1. 
I get the fullfilmentText to show in dialogflow, but cant make the carousel to show up.
What am I doing wrong?

Here is my method:

```
  [HttpPost]
  public ContentResult Post([FromBody] WebhookRequest webhookRequest)
  {
      var dialogflowResponse = new WebhookResponse { FulfillmentText = "FulfillmentText" };

      var carousel = new Intent.Types.Message.Types.CarouselSelect.Types.Item
      {
        Title = "My title",
          Description = "This is a description",
          Image = new Intent.Types.Message.Types.Image
          {
              ImageUri = "https://placekitten.com/200/300",
              AccessibilityText = "cat"
          },
          Info = new Intent.Types.Message.Types.SelectItemInfo
          {
              Key = "Cats"
           }
      };

      carousel.Info.Synonyms.Add("Synonym 1");
      carousel.Info.Synonyms.Add("Synonym 1");

      dialogflowResponse.FulfillmentMessages.Add(new Intent.Types.Message {
          CarouselSelect = new Intent.Types.Message.Types.CarouselSelect()
      });

      dialogflowResponse.FulfillmentMessages.First().CarouselSelect.Items.Add(carousel);

      return dialogflowResponse;
    }
```

Generates followiing Json:

```
{
    "fulfillmentText": "FulfillmentText",
    "fulfillmentMessages": [
        {
            "carouselSelect": {
                "items": [
                    {
                        "info": {
                            "key": "Cats",
                            "synonyms": [
                                "Synonym 1",
                                "Synonym 1"
                            ]
                        },
                        "title": "My title",
                        "description": "This is a description",
                        "image": {
                            "imageUri": "https://placekitten.com/200/300",
                            "accessibilityText": "cat"
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i ran into the same problem with the java api. Only the basic rich messages (card, quick replies, ...) are working. BasicCard, Suggestions, Carousel, ... doesn't show up in any channel.

I got it to work if i added some of the following custom payload to skype channel:

```
{
"skype": {
    "type": "message",
    "attachmentLayout": "carousel",
    "text": "Please select your food.",
    "attachments": [{
            "contentType": "application/vnd.microsoft.card.hero",
            "content": {
                "title": "Sushi",
                "subtitle": "Very fresh shrimp or tuna.",
                "images": [{
                        "url": "https://i.ibb.co/87LmvT3/mdi.png"
                    }
                ],
                "buttons": [{
                        "type": "imBack",
                        "title": "1 piece",
                        "value": "sushi,1"
                    }, {
                        "type": "imBack",
                        "title": "2 piece",
                        "value": "sushi,2"
                    }, {
                        "type": "imBack",
                        "title": "more",
                        "value": "sushi,3+"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }, {
            "contentType": "application/vnd.microsoft.card.hero",
            "content": {
                "title": "Tenpura",
                "subtitle": "Japanese first-class vegitables.",
                "images": [{
                        "url": "https://i.ibb.co/87LmvT3/mdi.png"
                    }
                ],
                "buttons": [{
                        "type": "imBack",
                        "title": "1 piece",
                        "value": "tenpura,1"
                    }, {
                        "type": "imBack",
                        "title": "2 piece",
                        "value": "tenpura,2"
                    }, {
                        "type": "imBack",
                        "title": "more",
                        "value": "tenpura,3+"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}}
```

I hope it helps!